# Why does my Flask app search results page need to be reloaded to display results only when served by nginx?

Tags: python, nginx, flask, production-environment, keyerror

I have set up a flask-based site that takes user input and makes a query to a postgres database. It works great when I run the app locally, but when I take it live on my vps, the search results in an error page. Except that if I hit reload (sometimes takes a few times), the results load as expected. Sometimes I have to hit reload a few times.

I suspect it might be related to nginx because if I just run the app and go directly on the vps with 'gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:5000' the app works as expected when I go to example.com:5000.

I found this in nginx error.log at the time of one of these failed searches:

```
2023/05/22 12:23:07 [warn] 994#994: *519 an upstream response is buffered to a temporary file /var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy/2/00/0000000002 while reading upstream, client: 216.227.60.13, server: , request: "GET /us_news HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/siteadmin/personal-website/siteapp.sock:/us_news", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/"
```

I found an error in my Flask app by turning on debugging. However I still need to figure out why this error would be fixed by simply reloading the page (why did the variable not exist on the first attempt to load, and then exist with subsequent reloads?):

```
ERROR:siteapp:Exception on /news_results [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/siteadmin/flask_venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2528, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/siteadmin/flask_venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1825, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/siteadmin/flask_venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1823, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/siteadmin/flask_venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/home/siteadmin/personal-website/siteapp/us_news/us_news.py", line 148, in news_results
    states = session['states']
  File "/home/siteadmin/flask_venv/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/flask/sessions.py", line 80, in __getitem__
    return super().__getitem__(key)
KeyError: 'states'
```

I tried adding time.sleep(5) right before the line that caused the error in hopes that it would give the application time to get the request from nginx, but no luck (but the page still loads properly after I hit reload a few times. Just with a 5-second delay on each reload.)

As per suggestions [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/nginx/comments/13ovmph/flask_app_search_results_page_needs_to_be/) I tried setting `proxy_request_buffering off;` in nginx.conf, but no luck.

My python code of the view in question is below: (I've been told I shouldn't be using a POST request for this as the POST data isn't actually being written to a database, but unless that is connected, I'd like to deal with it separately)

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, redirect, url_for, session, make_response
from flask import current_app as app, Flask, request, jsonify, g
from flask_paginate import Pagination, get_page_args
import json
import psycopg2
import click
from ..dbcon import makeConn
from datetime import datetime


from KnowledgeSchema import schema
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

def addError(error):
    with Session(schema.engine, expire_on_commit=False) as session:
        session.add(error)
        session.commit()
        # session.close()

# Blueprint Configuration
us_news_bp = Blueprint('us_news_bp', __name__,
                    url_prefix='',
                    template_folder='templates',
                    static_folder='static') 



def getArticles(states, topics, startDate, endDate):
    print(states)
    if states != '%':
        states = '|'.join(states)
    if topics != '%':
        topics = '|'.join(topics)
    search = {'states' : tuple(states), 'topics' : tuple(topics)}
    q = "select count(*) from articles"
    conn = makeConn()
    dict_cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
    dict_cur.execute(q)
    total = dict_cur.fetchone()[0]
    page, per_page, offset = get_page_args(
    page_parameter="p", per_page_parameter="pp", pp=20
    )
    if per_page:
        sqlStr = """
            SELECT title,pubdate,feed_id,articles.url,thumbnails[1],description,state_code,
            keywords, creators, news_outlets.outlet_name,news_outlets.main_url, news_outlets.mbfc_bias,
            news_outlets.mbfc_factual, news_outlets.mbfc_cred, news_outlets.twitter, news_outlets.mbfc_url, news_outlets.facebook, news_outlets.youtube, news_outlets.wikipedia,
            news_feeds.section as section, news_feeds.url AS feedurl, supersection, COUNT(*) OVER() AS num_rows
            FROM articles
            INNER JOIN news_feeds USING (feed_id)
            INNER JOIN states USING (state_id)
            INNER JOIN news_outlets USING (outlet_id)
            WHERE states.state_code SIMILAR TO %s
            AND supersection SIMILAR TO %s
            AND pubdate BETWEEN TO_DATE(%s, 'YYYY-MM-DD') and TO_DATE(%s, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
            ORDER BY pubdate_linux ASC LIMIT {} OFFSET {}
            """
        print(sqlStr)
        sql = dict_cur.mogrify(sqlStr.format(per_page, offset), (states, topics, startDate, endDate))
    else:
        sql = dict_cur.mogrify(
            """
            SELECT title,pubdate,feed_id,articles.url,thumbnails[1],description,state_code,
            keywords, creators, news_outlets.outlet_name,news_outlets.main_url, news_outlets.mbfc_bias,
            news_outlets.mbfc_factual, news_outlets.mbfc_cred, news_outlets.twitter, news_outlets.mbfc_url, news_outlets.facebook, news_outlets.youtube, news_outlets.wikipedia,
            news_feeds.section as section, news_feeds.url AS feedurl, supersection, COUNT(*) OVER() AS num_rows
            FROM articles
            INNER JOIN news_feeds USING (feed_id)
            INNER JOIN states USING (state_id)
            INNER JOIN news_outlets USING (outlet_id)
            WHERE states.state_code SIMILAR TO %s
            AND supersection SIMILAR TO %s
            AND pubdate BETWEEN TO_DATE(%s, 'YYYY-MM-DD') and TO_DATE(%s, 'YYYY-MM-DD'
            ORDER BY pubdate_linux ASC)
        """.format((states, topics, startDate, endDate)))
    print("sql is:", sql)
    print("SqL")
    dict_cur.execute(sql)
    articles = dict_cur.fetchall()
    total = articles[0][-1]
    pagination = get_pagination(
        p=page,
        pp=per_page,
        total=total,
        format_total=True,
        format_number=True,
        page_parameter="p",
        per_page_parameter="pp",
    )
    return articles, pagination


@us_news_bp.route('/us_news', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def us_news():
  if request.method == 'POST':
    states = request.form.getlist('jsonval')
    topics = request.form.getlist('topics')
    startDate = request.form.getlist('startDate')
    endDate = request.form.getlist('endDate')
    states = json.loads(states[0])
    print("start making session")
    try:
        session['states'] = states
    except:
        pass
    try:
        session['topics'] = topics
    except:
        pass
    try:
        session['startDate'] = startDate[0]
    except:
        pass
    try:
        session['endDate'] = endDate[0]
    except:
        pass
    print("END getting session")
    return redirect(url_for('us_news_bp.news_results', states=states, **request.args))
  else:
    q = "select DISTINCT supersection FROM articles;"
    conn = makeConn()
    dict_cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
    dict_cur.execute(q)
    topics = dict_cur.fetchall()
    return render_template('us_news.html',
                           title='Skeleton Site',
                           # states=states,
                           topics=topics,
                           subtitle='Homepage',
                           template='us_news-template')


def saveError(err):
    file = open("recent_error", "w")
    file.write(str(err))
    file.close()


@us_news_bp.route('/news_results')
def news_results():
    try:
        states = session['states']
        if len(states) == 0:
            states= '%'
        topics = session['topics']
        if len(topics) == 0:
            topics= '%'
        startDate = session['startDate']
        if len(startDate) == 0:
            startDate ='2000-01-01'
        endDate = session['endDate']
        if len(endDate) == 0:
            endDate = '2123-04-01'
        articles, pagination = getArticles(states, topics, startDate, endDate)
        return make_response(render_template(
                "news_results.html",
                articles=articles,
                pagination=pagination))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        saveError(e)
        failure = schema.Error(
                        error = str(e),
                        step = 'news search',
                        date = datetime.now().isoformat())
        return render_template("errorpage.html")


def get_css_framework():
    return app.config.get("CSS_FRAMEWORK", "bootstrap4")


def get_link_size():
    return app.config.get("LINK_SIZE", "sm")


def get_alignment():
    return app.config.get("LINK_ALIGNMENT", "")

def show_single_page_or_not():
    return app.config.get("SHOW_SINGLE_PAGE", False)


def get_pagination(**kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault("record_name", "records")
    return Pagination(
        css_framework=get_css_framework(),
        link_size=get_link_size(),
        alignment=get_alignment(),
        show_single_page=show_single_page_or_not(),
        **kwargs
    )


@click.command()
@click.option("--port", "-p", default=5000, help="listening port")
def run(port):
    app.run(debug=True, port=port)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```

my nginx configuration (the commented out lines are things I tried)

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 64;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;
    proxy_request_buffering off;


    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

#    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
#    default upgrade;
#    ''      close;
#}
    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
        # root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}


## site.conf

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
#       proxy_http_version 1.1;
#        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_request_buffering off;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/siteadmin/personal-website/siteapp.sock;
       # proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
#        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
#        proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
#        proxy_intercept_errors off;
    }
}


## Proxy proxy_params

proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem was that I was using a POST request when I should have been using GET. I have no idea why this only became a problem behind nginx, but restructuring my the function to GET as well as  using a GET method in the form seems to have solved the issue. The current version of the python file shown in my question looks like this:

```
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, redirect, url_for, session, make_response
from flask import current_app as app, Flask, request, jsonify, g, abort
from flask_paginate import Pagination, get_page_args
import json
import psycopg2
# import os
# from dotenv import load_dotenv
import click
from ..dbcon import makeConn
# from .StateAbbrs import stateAbbrs
from datetime import datetime


# load_dotenv('../../Secret/.env')
from KnowledgeSchema import schema
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

def addError(error):
    with Session(schema.engine, expire_on_commit=False) as session:
        session.add(error)
        session.commit()
        session.close()

# Blueprint Configuration
us_news_bp = Blueprint('us_news_bp', __name__,
                    url_prefix='',
                    template_folder='templates',
                    static_folder='static') 



def getArticles(states, topics, startDate, endDate):
    if states != '%':
        states = '|'.join(states)
    if topics != '%':
        topics = '|'.join(topics)
    search = {'states' : tuple(states), 'topics' : tuple(topics)}
    q = "select count(*) from articles"
    conn = makeConn()
    dict_cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
    dict_cur.execute(q)
    total = dict_cur.fetchone()[0]
    page, per_page, offset = get_page_args(
    page_parameter="p", per_page_parameter="pp", pp=20
    )
    if per_page:
        sqlStr = """
            SELECT title,pubdate,feed_id,articles.url,thumbnails[1],description,state_code,
            keywords, creators, news_outlets.outlet_name,news_outlets.main_url, news_outlets.mbfc_bias,
            news_outlets.mbfc_factual, news_outlets.mbfc_cred, news_outlets.twitter, news_outlets.mbfc_url, news_outlets.facebook, news_outlets.youtube, news_outlets.wikipedia,
            news_feeds.section as section, news_feeds.url AS feedurl, supersection, COUNT(*) OVER() AS num_rows
            FROM articles
            INNER JOIN news_feeds USING (feed_id)
            INNER JOIN states USING (state_id)
            INNER JOIN news_outlets USING (outlet_id)
            WHERE states.state_code SIMILAR TO %s
            AND supersection SIMILAR TO %s
            AND pubdate BETWEEN TO_DATE(%s, 'YYYY-MM-DD') and TO_DATE(%s, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
            ORDER BY pubdate_linux DESC LIMIT {} OFFSET {}
            """
        print(sqlStr)
        sql = dict_cur.mogrify(sqlStr.format(per_page, offset), (states, topics, startDate, endDate))
    else:
        sql = dict_cur.mogrify(
            """
            SELECT title,pubdate,feed_id,articles.url,thumbnails[1],description,state_code,
            keywords, creators, news_outlets.outlet_name,news_outlets.main_url, news_outlets.mbfc_bias,
            news_outlets.mbfc_factual, news_outlets.mbfc_cred, news_outlets.twitter, news_outlets.mbfc_url, news_outlets.facebook, news_outlets.youtube, news_outlets.wikipedia,
            news_feeds.section as section, news_feeds.url AS feedurl, supersection, COUNT(*) OVER() AS num_rows
            FROM articles
            INNER JOIN news_feeds USING (feed_id)
            INNER JOIN states USING (state_id)
            INNER JOIN news_outlets USING (outlet_id)
            WHERE states.state_code SIMILAR TO %s
            AND supersection SIMILAR TO %s
            AND pubdate BETWEEN TO_DATE(%s, 'YYYY-MM-DD') and TO_DATE(%s, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
            ORDER BY pubdate_linux DESC
        """.format((states, topics, startDate, endDate)))
    dict_cur.execute(sql)
    articles = dict_cur.fetchall()
    if len(articles) == 0:
        return None, None
    total = articles[0][-1]
    pagination = get_pagination(
        p=page,
        pp=per_page,
        total=total,
        format_total=True,
        format_number=True,
        page_parameter="p",
        per_page_parameter="pp",
    )
    conn.close()
    return articles, pagination


@us_news_bp.route('/us_news')
def us_news():
    states = request.form.get('states')
    q = "select DISTINCT supersection FROM articles;"
    conn = makeConn()
    dict_cur = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.DictCursor)
    dict_cur.execute(q)
    topics = dict_cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    return render_template('us_news.html',
                           title='Find news by state and topic',
                           # states=states,
                           topics=topics,
                           subtitle='Homepage',
                           template='us_news-template')


def saveError(err):
    file = open("recent_error", "w")
    file.write(str(err))
    file.close()


@us_news_bp.route('/news_results')
def news_results():
    try:
        states = request.args.get('jsonval')
        states = json.loads(states)
        if len(states) == 0:
            states= '%'
        topics = request.args.getlist('topics')
        if len(topics) == 0:
            topics = '%'
        startDate = request.args.get('startDate')
        if len(startDate) == 0:
            startDate ='2000-01-01'
        endDate = request.args.get('endDate')
        if len(endDate) == 0:
            endDate = '2123-05-24'
        articles, pagination = getArticles(states, topics, startDate, endDate)
        if articles == None:
            return render_template('err404.html'), 404
        return make_response(render_template(
                "news_results.html",
                articles=articles,
                pagination=pagination))
    except Exception as e:
        saveError(e)
        failure = schema.Error(
                        error = str(e),
                        step = 'news search',
                        date = datetime.now().isoformat())
        return render_template("errorpage.html")


def get_css_framework():
    return app.config.get("CSS_FRAMEWORK", "bootstrap4")


def get_link_size():
    return app.config.get("LINK_SIZE", "sm")


def get_alignment():
    return app.config.get("LINK_ALIGNMENT", "")

def show_single_page_or_not():
    return app.config.get("SHOW_SINGLE_PAGE", False)


def get_pagination(**kwargs):
    kwargs.setdefault("record_name", "records")
    return Pagination(
        css_framework=get_css_framework(),
        link_size=get_link_size(),
        alignment=get_alignment(),
        show_single_page=show_single_page_or_not(),
        **kwargs
    )


@click.command()
@click.option("--port", "-p", default=5000, help="listening port")
def run(port):
    app.run(debug=True, port=port)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```